# Read checkbox status from django

Tags: javascript, django, checkbox

I'm writting a Django App.

At this moment I'm displaying a list of data using the django template. 
With each data I put a checkbox, directly as an html tag.

```
{% for event in latest_events_list %}
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_delete" name="event" id="event.id"
         value="{{ event.id }}" />
    </td>
<td>{{ event.date }}</td> 
<td>{{ event.time }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I also put a "selectAll" checkbox that works with a js code

```
<input type="checkbox"  id="selectAll"  />
<label for="selectAll"> Select</label>
```

js code

```
$("#selectAll").change(function() {
   $(".checkbox_delete:checkbox").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Now I need to read the status of every checkbox with a django view, after click a submit button.  I  replaced the "selectAll" checkbox with a BooleanField from a DjangoForm (which include the submit button),  but I dont know how to read the rest of checkboxes status.

Do I need to use a django form for every data?, or there is a more simple way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are sending the form as a POST, the values of the selected checkboxes are in `request.POST.getlist('event')`.

Note that only checked boxes are ever sent in the POST, but the list contains the `value` elements of all the boxes that are checked.

Comment: but the events doesnt belong to the form. With the request.POST i just get the status of the selectAll checkbox

Comment: What form? The HTML `<form>` element? So why aren't they? If you want them to be sent in the POST, they need to be inside the `<form>` element.

Comment: @PabloV. what can be the minimalistic way to get the values of selected elements (list of records, using chekcboxes) from template to the view, without using <form> hence also not via POST.getlist()